# How to parse specific table when tables have identical class names with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Edit:

I get how to parse a table with beautifulsoup (I'm using bs4) but the specific page I'm trying to scrape right now has 10 tables with identical class values.

My code fragment works for the first table:

```
    data = []
    table = YahooSoup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table-qsp-stats Mt(10px)'})
    table_body = table.find('tbody')

    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

    YahooData = pd.DataFrame(data)
    MarketCap = YahooData.at[0,1]
```

How can I tell the program to parse a different table other than the first one since all the table class values are equal to 'table-qsp-stats Mt(10px)'?

The page link is https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CBG/key-statistics?p=CBG

If this question has already been answered I would also appreciate a link to that answer. I honestly could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by making your objects lowercase.  Leading capitals are for class names ONLY.  YahooSoup should be yahoo_soup or yahooSoup, etc.

You could always use pd.concat to concatenate multiple dataframes.

Or you could create a series of dataframes and index into that

Comment: I would concatenate the data frames but I can only parse the first table because when I tell it to parse another table it still only parses the first table because the classes are the same. All the classes are equal to 'table-qsp-stats Mt(10px)' so how could I specify to do the second table? or the third? etc... Should I add [2] to somewhere in the code line?

Comment: If you replace `table = soup.find(...` with `tables = soup.find_all(...`, then you can iterate over them tables and do with them as you want (Like ChootsMaggots suggests if I understood correctly)